# Regex expression for the below format

Tags: c++, regex

I need to write the regex expression for below format for c++ regex

```
Ffs\\2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56PiSmmIpl\\2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56.map
```

Here I need to get the string

```
2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56PiSmmIpl
```

Means GUID followed by character

I am trying this but did not works

```
[0-9A-Fa-f{9}]+-[0-9A-Fa-f{4}]+-[0-9A-Fa-f{4}]+-[0-9A-Fa-f{4}]+-[0-9A-Fa-f{12}].*\\$
```

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Limiting quantifiers should be placed after `]`. And remove `+` then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i am not getting can u please elaborate

Comment: Well, you also use `.*` that matches to the end of the string, but you want to match up to the next ``\``, so also replace `.*$` with ``[^\\]*``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried this in c++ 
([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[^\\\]*) but it gives me exception

Comment: Sure, you must use a raw string literal, `std::regex rx(R"(<pattern_here>)")` (replace `<pattern_here>` with the pattern). Please post the full relevant code in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry to trouble you
I am compiling this code in VS2010 and it simply gives it error R undefined
regex rgx1(R"([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[^\\]*)");

Comment: Ok,then instead of ``\\`` use ``\\\\``.

Comment: many thanks for your help it works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
if I need to get only PiSmmIpl from 
2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56PiSmmIpl  what regex should i write

Comment: Ok, do you want to get both values in 1 go?

Comment: no first i get 2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56PiSmmIpl
Then from this i need to construct only PiSmmIpl and 2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56
I have the pattern for constructing 2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56 but i am not sure how can i get PiSmmIpl from it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi I need your help
I need to regex expression for below format
string1  string2     string3 string4 "This is my string"
There are 5 strings in above row all are separated by spaces they can be separated by multiple spaces also.I need the all 5 strings but in separately how can i do this using regex for c++

Please note that i don't want to seprate strings based on spaces inside quotes aka "This is my string"
I am not able ask further question stackoverflow blocked me that's why i am asking here thanks for help

Comment: [Here you go](https://ideone.com/ocu3rN).

Comment: I am using VS2010 hence i was not able to compile this instance of code
std::sregex_token_iterator srti(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), rx, {1, 2});

Comment: Ok, just push the `m[1].str()` or `m[2].str()` to the final vector if they aren't empty.

Comment: std::sregex_token_iterator srti(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), rx, -1);
I did this but did not worked

Comment: Remove -1 altogether. You do not need the argument at all.

Comment: done many thanks for your help

Comment: can you suggest me any books for improving regex expression knowledge

Comment: No need reading books. Use http://regexone.com, then all you need is here, on SO, or http://regular-expressions.info.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok thanks for your help one last question why did you use (std::string const &s) { return s.empty();  for below

std::remove_copy_if(srti, std::sregex_token_iterator(), 
                 std::back_inserter(tokens),
                 [](std::string const &s) { return s.empty(); });

Comment: There are empty items when one capturing group matches and the other doesn't. That code removed empty  items.

Comment: I need one more help I need to write expressions for  which can separate files.. in below format..
Test1/Test2/Test3\Test4.txt

Hence I need last Test4.txt value

Comment: See https://ideone.com/qGGrqy

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it worked. I upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
std::regex rx("[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){3}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}([^\\\\]*)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k20I8B/1). Basically, move the limiting quantifiers outside character classes while removing `+` quantifiers, then make sure `\` is properly  escaped (in a non-raw string literal, `\\\\`), and finally match any 0+ chars other than `\` using `[^\\]*` construct.

**Details**

- `[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}` - 8 hex chars
- `(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){3}` - 3 occurrences of 4 hex chars separated with `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}` - 12 hex chars
- `([^\\]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `\`.

[C++ demo](https://ideone.com/6WDo6N):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex rex1("[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}(?:-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){3}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}([^\\\\]*)");
    string s("Ffs\\2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56PiSmmIpl\\2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56.map");
    smatch m;
    if (regex_search(s, m, rex1)) {
        std::cout << "Whole match: " << m[0] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PiSmmIpl value: " << m[1] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Whole match: 2FA2A6DA-11D5-4dc3-999A-749648B03C56PiSmmIpl
PiSmmIpl value: PiSmmIpl
```